# Django: Possible to save a method, class or object to a database

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

Is it possible to store a method, class or object to a database for later retrieval and use?
How would I go about this?

Comment: You need to elaborate more. Provide a use case and describe the motivation. Otherwise it is "too broad" (haven't downvoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases store data.  Not code.  There really is not any point to storing the code either since you will be using code to read your data back out.  That being said you can save the data that makes up an object such that it can be reconstructed.  You would need some way to serialize your object.  For instance if you json the object data and stored that, you would have the data needed to recreate the object later.  But a better way is to look at what data really needs to be stored and only store that.